# migrating infopath forms using sharegate not working - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, forms-services, share

I'm doing some migration of list(customised infopath form) using sharegate but when i go and try and open the form after migration the form opens up using the out of the box form and not infopath.
The correct site features and site collection features have been activated.
Has anyone faced any similar issue?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In case it helps, infopath services are not available on all office 365 licences. E3 has it, but E1 doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

After migration, you need to re-publish the form into your list.

Try to re-publish the form and then check the results.

Note: InfoPath forms are currently not supported on Modern experience list on Office 365, it can only work in classic experience list.

Comment: Thanks for that but i can't get to see the Customize in infopath icon in the ribbon.Its not showing up and i have activated the correct features as mentioned in my original post

Comment: Do you mean modern experience list? pay attention that InfoPath forms are currently not supported on Modern experience list. If you are saying classic list, then you should go to Microsoft 365 Admin center > SharePoint admin center > Infopath. Select the "Allow users to browser-enable form templates" 
and "Render form templates that are browser-enabled by users" check box.

Comment: Thanks and yes its not Modern but classic. Will check the Admin center and see if its enable.Is this optioned based on site collections?

Comment: This option is for your tenant.

Comment: Thanks. The option  "Customize the InfoPath link in the ribbon" is no there. But when I click on it its displaying the out of the box form and it seems shagate didn't migrate the customised form in InfoPath.
Are there steps I have to do in sharegate for this to work?

Comment: Another update ... now when i go and open a new form or edit a an existing form i get a blank page.It . I have republished the infopath form and it said successful